# JTextArea connot be converted to int, Jscroll in Jpanel issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I've found some similar answers but none that have helped my solve this issue. For some reason in my createMiddlePanel method, my JtextArea *txaResults* is giving me an area saying, JTextArea connot be converted to int. Any assistance would be helpful. I'm not sure if this has to do with it being in a panel but I can't think of any other reason why I would be getting an error.

```
package Tell;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FortuneTellerFrame extends JFrame {

JPanel pnlTop, pnlMiddle, pnlBottom;
JButton btnSubmit, btnQuit;
JLabel  lblFortuneTeller, lblPassword;
JTextField txtFortuneTeller, txtPassword;
JTextArea txaResults;
JScrollPane jsp;
public FortuneTellerFrame() {
    add(this.createTopPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(this.createMiddlePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(this.createBottomPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Always set the size of data and the default close operation. 
    // Visibility needs to be set to true to be seen as well
    this.setSize(400, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


   }
   private JPanel createTopPanel()
   {
       pnlTop = new JPanel();
       pnlTop.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
       ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("ball.jpg");
       Image image1 = icon.getImage(); // transform it 
       Image newimg = image1.getScaledInstance(50, 50,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
       icon = new ImageIcon(newimg); // transform back

       JLabel label = new JLabel("Fortune Teller",icon,JLabel.LEFT);
       label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
       label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
       lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
       txtFortuneTeller = new JTextField(10);
       txtPassword = new JTextField(10);

       pnlTop.add(label);
       pnlTop.add(txtFortuneTeller);
       pnlTop.add(lblPassword);
       pnlTop.add(txtPassword);

       return pnlTop;
    }

   private JPanel createMiddlePanel()
   {
       pnlMiddle = new JPanel();
       txaResults = new JTextArea(10, 30);
       jsp = new JScrollPane(txaResults, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
       pnlMiddle.add(jsp);

       return pnlMiddle;
   }
   private JPanel createBottomPanel()
   {
       pnlBottom = new JPanel();
       btnSubmit = new JButton("Read My Fortune!");
       btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");

      btnQuit.addActionListener(e ->{
          System.exit(0);
      });

      btnSubmit.addActionListener(e ->{
          String username = this.txtFortuneTeller.getText();
          String password = this.txtPassword.getText();

          this.txaResults.append("Attempting to login with username " 
                  + username + " and password " + password + "\n");
      });

       pnlBottom.add(btnSubmit);
       pnlBottom.add(btnQuit);

       return pnlBottom;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
private JPanel createMiddlePanel()
{
   pnlMiddle = new JPanel();
   txaResults = new JTextArea(10, 30);
   jsp = new JScrollPane(txaResults);
   jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
   pnlMiddle.add(jsp);

   return pnlMiddle;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and I got an error with this line:

```
jsp = new JScrollPane(txaResults, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

the JScrollPane expect the component and 2 integer, pointing to the vertical scrolling and the horizontal, so if you add the other argument, it should work,

```
private JPanel createMiddlePanel()
   {
       pnlMiddle = new JPanel();
       txaResults = new JTextArea(10, 30);
       jsp = new JScrollPane(txaResults, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
       pnlMiddle.add(jsp);

       return pnlMiddle;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not sure why it required a value for hoizontalScroll but that did seem to do the trick. ty

Comment: @BallaBaby Because [the constructor documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#constructor.summary) clearly shows there are no constructors which take a component and a single int as arguments.

Comment: @VGR well would you look at that